# nRF24L01: Serial monitor responds on interchanging CE and CSN

Tags: arduino

I connected the nRF24L01 pins with CE=pin 7 and CSN=Pin 8, exactly the way NRF Library documentation mentions.

1. On connecting to 3.3V, the serial monitor does not display any 'print' data command, but surprisingly it starts responding on interchanging 7 and 8 pins.
2. When I remove both CE and CSN connections from Arduino, the serial monitor shows some sends and receives.

I am confused why this happens, and why there is no response on serial monitor when I connect exactly the way documentation says.

please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

there is lack of talent on this site. the answers are not upto the point, people post conflicting responses. I always have to post to other forums to confirm it. I have stopped using this forum.
half knowledge is dangerous thing.